# Firebase Realtime Database security rules regular expression: Normal Javastring regex doesn't get accepted in .matches()

Tags: regex, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have this regex: `/^(?=[^A-Za-z]*([A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*){6}$)\w+$/`

But it doesn't get accepted in .validate's matches().
Shows invalid character and other such errors.

```
"$username": {
        // here
        ".validate": "$username.matches(/^(?=[^A-Za-z]*([A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*){6}$)\w+$/)",
        ".write": "(auth.uid != null && newData.val() === auth.uid) || (auth != null && !newData.exists())"
}
```

What all changes do I need to make to expression to make it accept in rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this page [Firebase Security Rules Regular Expressions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex) lookarounds and non capture groups do not seem to be supported.

You might write the pattern without any lookarounds, repeat a capture group 6 times and only use `\w` as that is only allowed to match:

```
^\w*([A-Za-z]\w*){6}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\w*` Match optional leading word chars
- `([A-Za-z]\w*){6}` Match 6 times a char A-Z a-z followed by optional trailing word chars
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jf6d3V/1).

The final working command according to the comments:

```
".validate": "$username.matches(/^\\w*([A-Za-z]\\w*){6,}$/)",
```

Comment: still says invalid escape: \w

Comment: @ShouryaShikhar Did you try `\\w` ? like `.matches(/^\\w*([A-Za-z]\\w*){6}$/)`

Comment: yeah tried. then says syntax error

Comment: @ShouryaShikhar What is the exact error message?

Comment: on hovering, just shows `syntax error`

Comment: @ShouryaShikhar Are you sure that the overall syntax is correct? I have never used firebase syntax, can you use $username like that?

Comment: yes the original syntax is correct, I am using that in my application as well. Just not sure why firebase doesn't accept it.

Comment: @ShouryaShikhar Does using a basic expression like `.matches(/^.+$/)` work?

Comment: @ShouryaShikhar And the same expression without backslashes `^[A-Za-z0-9_]*([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*){6}$`

Comment: no gives syntax error

Comment: @ShouryaShikhar Perhaps this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#validaterules is helpful. It states that `Enforcing data structures and validating the format and content of data should be done using .validate rules, which are run only after a .write rule succeeds to grant access. ` Should you run it the other way around?

Comment: Thanks. Ultimately this has worked: `".validate": "$username.matches(/^\\w*([A-Za-z]\\w*){6,}$/)",`

Comment: @ShouryaShikhar Ah cool, so it is with the doubled escapes :-) Let me update that in the answer for other readers. Using `{6,}` matches 6 or more times.